# Ruby on Rails: a simpler Hash.slice method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

In http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Hash.html#method-i-slice, I see

```
valid_keys = [:mass, :velocity, :time]
search(options.slice(*valid_keys))
```

I don't get the usage here. I mean, if I pass an `array` into `slice`, I definitely want every `key` get sliced, then why use an addtional `*` here?

Is is possible to make it into something like:

```
valid_keys = [:mass, :velocity, :time]
search(options.simple_slice(valid_keys))
```

by creating a simpler version of `slice`?

Comment: Is your question more of "why do you need to splat an array" for this method's argument?  Ref: [Hash](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/b670fadb978c8a12c3414ed842cd49e4fde2cec0/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/hash/slice.rb#L21)

Comment: @vee, well, I actually read the source code, even though I'm not quite understand it. But the main concer is that I think `slice` should do the dirty work, I'm not sure if this thinking is right or not.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Hashes can have all sorts of things for keys, the keys don't have to be just strings or symbols. For example, this is a perfectly valid Hash:

```
{ [ :mass, :velocity, :time ] => 'pancakes' }
```

How is `Hash#slice` supposed to know that sometimes this:

```
h.slice([:mass, :velocity, :time])
```

means "give me the sub-hash with those three keys" and sometimes it means "give me the sub-hash with that array as a key"?

`Hash#slice` takes a list of keys (one key per argument) so if you want to have your keys in an array then you have to splat them into individual arguments:

```
h.slice(*some_array_of_keys)
# ------^ expand the array into individual arguments
```

That's why you need the `*`.

If you want to assume that the keys will never be arrays then you're free to say something like:

```
def simple_slice(*keys) # Allow any number of arguments
  slice(*keys.flatten)  # flatten all the arrays and then punt to Rails's slice.
end
```

You might not want to flatten only one level (or maybe you don't).

Comment: I kind of sense that you are saying `array.flatten` is same as `*array`?  Am I confused?  The two return different results when tested on OP's question.  And if `simple_slice(*keys)` is declared as such, it's no different than Rails's `active_support/core_ext/hash/slice.rb#slice`, itsn't it?

Comment: @vee: No, they're very different. `flatten` flattens all the nested arrays (if any), `*array` is used to match `Hash#slice`'s variadic behavior. Try `{ [1,2] => 3, [4,5] => 6 }.slice([1,2])` and `{ [1,2] => 3, [4,5] => 6 }.slice(1,2)` and you'll see the difference.

Answer (score 3):

Anything's possible.

Here's the original source code for `Hash#slice`, as shown in the [link from your question](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Hash.html#method-i-slice):

```
def slice(*keys)
  keys.map! { |key| convert_key(key) } if respond_to?(:convert_key, true)
  keys.each_with_object(self.class.new) { |k, hash| hash[k] = self[k] if has_key?(k) }
end
```

And here's how you might do it to save yourself that keystroke.

```
def simple_slice(keys)
  keys.map! { |key| convert_key(key) } if respond_to?(:convert_key, true)
  keys.each_with_object(self.class.new) { |k, hash| hash[k] = self[k] if has_key?(k) }
end
```

Obviously, however, such a `simple_slice` is less flexible: the original slice allows for an arbitrary number of keys to passed as individual arguments, e.g. `options.slice(:mass, :velocity, :time)` in addition to a splatted array `options.slice(*valid_keys)`, but the `simple_slice` will support only arrays.

Answer (score 1):

You need to splat an array passed as an argument into #slice because you need to be clear whether the array contains a list of the desired keys or ***is*** the desired key. Almost anything, including an Array, can be a Hash key in ruby.

```
h = { 1 => "one", 2 => "two", [1,2] => "I'm an array!" }
array = [1,2]
h.slice(array)  => {[1, 2]=>"I'm an array!"}
h.slice(1,2)    => {1=>"one", 2=>"two"}
h.slice(*array) => {1=>"one", 2=>"two"}
```

The splat operator destructures the array for use as multiple arguments rather than using it as single Array argument.